# jQuery form plugin passing context in request and response

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I'm using the [jQuery forms plugin](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/) within an object, for example:

```
var myObject = {

  el : $('#form'),

  init : function() {

    var options = {
        beforeSubmit: this.submitRequest,
        success: this.submitResponse,
        error: function(xhr, reply, error) {

        }
    };

    this.el.ajaxForm(options);

  },
  submitRequest : function(formData, jqForm, options) {

     //this no longer contains the el attribute or access to any other myObject properties     
     console.log(this);

  },
  submitResponse : function() {

  }

};
```

You can see this in case, that beforeSubmit it's calling `this.submitRequest`, but within that function, I can't get the context of myObject.  Any ideas how to pass the context or access other properties of myObject?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `context` property of ajax.

```
var options = {
    context: this
};
```